# Use other resource location for a new one in Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-virtual-network

In an ARM template in Azure, I am trying to create a load balancer attached to an existing VNet.

The issue is related to the location: the VNet and the resource groups are not in the same location, and the load balancer can only be created in the same location as the VNet (which make sense), so I can't use 'resourceGroup().location'.

According to [reference function's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference), I can use it in the definition of a new resource, but when I define the location from the load balancer with the reference to the VNet, I get an error.

Extract from the definition:

```
"resources": [
    {
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "name": "[parameters('loadBalancerName')]",
    "location": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/VirtualNetworks',parameters('vNetName')),'2022-01-01','Full').location]",
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
    },
    "properties": {
```

Previously, I was using 'resourceGroup().location' as the VNet were always in the same location as the resource group.

With this code, I get the following error:

`{"code": "InvalidTemplate", "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'mytemplate' at line '28' and column '5' is not valid: The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.", "additionalInfo": [{"type": "TemplateViolation", "info": {"lineNumber": 28, "linePosition": 5, "path": "properties.template.resources[0]"}}]}`

I don't want to specify as parameter the VNet location, as it already exists, and I should be table to retrieve it from the name I'm already providing.

When I try to use the `reference` function in variables, I get an error it can't be used in variables.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this scenario in my lab for validation. I will also check with the backend team to see if there are any known issues with the reference function and provide an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

*reference* function only works with outputs section of a template or deployment and properties object of a resource definition

This is an expected behavior and the document has been updated here.

[image]

**Refer**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#valid-uses-1

Comment: but that's exactly what I'm trying to do: use the reference in the definition of a new resource ! or does that mean something else?

Comment: The reference function is only supported for certain properties only and that does not include top level properties such as "location", which is your case.
You can use it inside the properties section of a resource definition, i.,e
This is supported,
IP1:
"properties": {
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 15
      }
IP2:
"properties": {
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses1')),'2022-01-01','Full').properties.idleTimeoutInMinutes]"
      }

Comment: the problem is that the documentation doesn't explicit where you can use reference, so it's everyone best guess ?
Sorry, but the documentation and the error are quite useless in this case

on top of that, it doesn't answer the question on how I can retrieve the location of an object and use it in another one

Comment: in your scenario, I am afraid you will not be able to fetch the location dynamically. You have to hard code the location or use variables/parameters.

Comment: so there is no way to dynamically use the location of another resource ? that's a astonishing and annoying miss in the implementation

Comment: I shall work internally and try to update the document to include more use cases for "reference" method. You can raise a feedback item here : https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/ . Our Product group closely monitors this hub for product enhancements and new feature requests